# shell script syntax: variable name to reference array

Tags: arrays, bash, shell, variables

This is close, but I'm having trouble referencing the second array in my loop. What should the syntax look like? $item is returning "1" instead of "a,b,c or d"

```
colors=( teal purple pink red green darkblue skyblue )
teal=( a b c d )


for color in ${colors[@]}
do
    echo $color

    for item in ${#{$color}[@]}
    do
        echo $item
    done

done
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do something like this:

mkt.sh

```
colors=( teal purple pink red green darkblue skyblue )
teal=( a b c d )
purple=( x y z )

for color in ${colors[@]}
do
    echo color: $color

    declare -a 'vals=("${'"$color"'[@]}")'
    for item in ${vals[@]}
    do
        echo "-- $item"
    done
done
```

Running:

```
$ ./mkt.sh 
color: teal
-- a
-- b
-- c
-- d
color: purple
-- x
-- y
-- z
color: pink
color: red
color: green
color: darkblue
color: skyblue
$
```

Credits:

- http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays, section **Indirection**